# Go to beginning of text field in Mac.

Tags: macos, text-editor

What's the keyboard combination to use to go to the very beginning of a text field?

Tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and it scrolls the document up but doesn't move the cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> **or** <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> will take you to the beginning of the text field, while <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> **or** <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> will take you to the end of it.

Comment: Command+Right won't take you to the beginning of a multi-line text field, but Command+Up will.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to move to the beginning of the text field, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to move to the end. This works in all Cocoa-based apps.